# Merging objects in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, merge, array-merge

I have some objects that I'm trying to merge them together in Node.js
First object is in a format like this

`{ ids : [id, id, id, ....]}`

Rest of the  object is in a format like this

```
{ postcode: '' , lat: '', lon: ''}, {postcode: '' , lat: '', lon: ''},....
```

I need to merger them in a way that looks like a format similar to this

```
{ id: '', postcode: '', lat: '', lon:''}
```

I was wondering would it be possible to do that in nodejs?

Comment: are the data related at the same index? do you want to get new objects with `id` and `lat`, `lon` without `postcode`?

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes they are related. so I want to add every id in the array to an object. for example id at first index of the array to the first object, id at second index of array to second object and so on. Eventually I will multiple objects or a single array that contains  `{id: , postcode:, lat:, lon:,}....`

Comment: @ScottSauyet I have tried looping through them and merge them but some reason, I either miss an object or the data never match. The problem is I am java developer and now working with node and its async nature has really confused me!

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this to merge a query of `id`s with an array of `results` from a database? If so, depending on the database, the objects can already contain the `id` if you tweak the query parameters.

Comment: The point was the **[you really should](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** include some discussion in your question about what you've done so far, usually by showing some code.

Answer (score 2):

#### ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) Standard Method

```js
Object.assign(obj1, obj2);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Using function `forEach`.

> Assuming the objects are both within the same array.

```js
var array = [{ ids : ['5a6df69d84a1d08d9104c0b2', '5a6df69d84a1d08d9104c0b3', '5a6df69d84a1d08d9104c0b4']}, { postcode: 'BL9 9LS', lat: 53.5784531917354, lon: -2.30434868940289, admin_ward: 'E05000682' }, { postcode: 'SK3 0RH', lat: 53.4003081612165, lon: -2.19362957330647, admin_ward: 'E05000788' }, { postcode: 'BS1 5BQ', lat: 51.4564431573373, lon: -2.59829088044349, admin_ward: 'E05010892' }];

var result = array.slice(-(array.length - 1)); // Create a new Array removing the first position.
result.forEach((e, i) => e['id'] = array[0].ids[i] /* Add id from the first element*/);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

> Separated objects
>
> *This approach modifies the source array.*

```js
var firstObject = { ids : ['5a6df69d84a1d08d9104c0b2', '5a6df69d84a1d08d9104c0b3', '5a6df69d84a1d08d9104c0b4']};
var array = [{ postcode: 'BL9 9LS', lat: 53.5784531917354, lon: -2.30434868940289, admin_ward: 'E05000682' }, { postcode: 'SK3 0RH', lat: 53.4003081612165, lon: -2.19362957330647, admin_ward: 'E05000788' }, { postcode: 'BS1 5BQ', lat: 51.4564431573373, lon: -2.59829088044349, admin_ward: 'E05010892' }];

array.forEach((e, i) => e['id'] = firstObject.ids[i]);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

## Using function `map`.

> Assuming the objects are both within the same array.

```js
var array = [{ ids : ['5a6df69d84a1d08d9104c0b2', '5a6df69d84a1d08d9104c0b3', '5a6df69d84a1d08d9104c0b4']}, { postcode: 'BL9 9LS', lat: 53.5784531917354, lon: -2.30434868940289, admin_ward: 'E05000682' }, { postcode: 'SK3 0RH', lat: 53.4003081612165, lon: -2.19362957330647, admin_ward: 'E05000788' }, { postcode: 'BS1 5BQ', lat: 51.4564431573373, lon: -2.59829088044349, admin_ward: 'E05010892' }];

var result = array.slice(-(array.length - 1)); // Create a new Array removing the first position.
result = result.map((e, i) => ({ ...e, ...{'id': array[0].ids[i] } }) /* Add id from the first element*/);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

> Separated objects

```js
var firstObject = { ids : ['5a6df69d84a1d08d9104c0b2', '5a6df69d84a1d08d9104c0b3', '5a6df69d84a1d08d9104c0b4']};
var array = [{ postcode: 'BL9 9LS', lat: 53.5784531917354, lon: -2.30434868940289, admin_ward: 'E05000682' }, { postcode: 'SK3 0RH', lat: 53.4003081612165, lon: -2.19362957330647, admin_ward: 'E05000788' }, { postcode: 'BS1 5BQ', lat: 51.4564431573373, lon: -2.59829088044349, admin_ward: 'E05010892' }];

var result = array.map((e, i) => ({ ...e, ...{ 'id': firstObject.ids[i] } }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: These are great answers, thank you! However, my array in your answer is not inside an array so its like `{},{},{}` and when i push it into an array then I get the result i want but it never increments. So, its the same id for all the objects! Any Idea how to increment it?

Comment: @M.Asgari can you share the input and output in your question to understand better what you're looking for?

Comment: So these are my inputs, `{ postcode: 'BL9 9LS',
  lat: 53.5784531917354,
  lon: -2.30434868940289,
  admin_ward: 'E05000682' }
{ postcode: 'SK3 0RH',
  lat: 53.4003081612165,
  lon: -2.19362957330647,
  admin_ward: 'E05000788' }
{ postcode: 'BS1 5BQ',
  lat: 51.4564431573373,
  lon: -2.59829088044349,
  admin_ward: 'E05010892' }`  which is the first input then i have another input which is `{ ids: 
   [ 5a6df69d84a1d08d9104c0b2,
     5a6df69d84a1d08d9104c0b3,
     5a6df69d84a1d08d9104c0b4]}`

Comment: my output should be these two merged, like `{id(each one unique) : ' ' , postcode: ' ' , lat: ' ', lon: ' ' }...... `

Comment: @M.Asgari the inputs are within an array?

Comment: The ids are inside an array. The rest are just json objects! none of them are inside an array and when i try to push them in an array they turn into a strange format

Comment: @M.Asgari can you share what you've tried so far?  for a better understanding.  Use JSFiddle for example or share that in your question.

Comment: so this approach at the moment, adds the first id to all the objects in pcs

Comment: @M.Asgari the code you've shared is totally invalid.  You need to understand how to create objects, functions, Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Object.assign mutates your objects.

```
let idsObj = { ids : [id, id, id, ....]};

let postCodeArray = [{ postcode: '' , lat: '', lon: ''}, {postcode: '' , lat: '', lon: ''}];

postCodeArray.forEach((elem,index) => Object.assign(elem,{id: idsObj.ids[index]}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could prepend the object with the `id`.

```js
var object1 = { ids: [23, 42] },
    postcodes = [{ postcode: 'XY' , lat: '11', lon: '22' }, { postcode: 'ZY' , lat: '33', lon: '44'}],
    merged = postcodes.map((o, i) => Object.assign({ id: object1.ids[i] }, o));
    
console.log(merged);
```